# Not seeing spreadsheets created with Drive/Sheets API (Python)

Tags: python, google-sheets, drive

I have looked all over the forums and documentation to try to understand what I am missing here, but I'm also very new to Python so could be making a simple mistake. I am trying to create a spreadsheet in a shared folder, then share that sheet with my main account (using a service account to create the sheet because not sure if there is another way). I can create the sheet in the shared drive but I can't see to see the newly created sheets even while applying shared permissions without receiving any errors. Here is what I have so far
`

```
from __future__ import print_function
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
]


# Get credentials
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', SCOPES)

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Name sheet and provide parent ID of shared folder within shared drive
sheet_metadata = {
    'name': 'This will be cools',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
    'parents': 'SHARED FOLDER ID INSIDE SHARED DRIVE',
}

# Sharing permissions
shared_permissions = {
    'role': 'writer',
    'type': 'user',
    'emailAddress': 'MY PERSONAL EMAIL'
}

results = service.files().create(body=sheet_metadata,fields='id').execute()

permission = service.permissions().create(
    fileId=results.get('id'),
    body=shared_permissions
)
```

`

I was having trouble figuring out how to pass the ID of the newly created sheet given that I don't have it because it is being created, but it seems this is working but still cannot see the new sheet when I access the shared folder in the shared drive. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answered my own question after taking a step away and getting another look. I was missing .execute() after adjusting permissions. Added and works to create and share and see the sheet!

Answer (score 0):

I was missing .execute() after adjusting permissions. Here is the correct permissions portion with slight adjustment to grab the sheet id right before that works perfect to create a sheet and make it visible.

```
sheet_id = results.get('id')   


permissions = service.permissions().create(
    fileId=sheet_id, body=shared_permissions).execute()
```